# Matlab: display full error path

Tags: matlab

Consider the following `foo.m` file:

```
try
    disp(r3)
catch ME
    disp(getReport(ME))
end
```

When I run it with:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -wait -r "run('foo.m')"
```

I get:

```
Undefined function or variable 'r3'.

Error in foo (line 2)
    disp(r3)

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to display the full path of those files that are referenced in the errors. I know I can use `which` and, for instance, get:

```
» which run
C:\prog-lang\matlab\toolbox\matlab\lang\run.m
```

But I would like the errors to be directly displayed like

```
Error in C:\prog-lang\matlab\toolbox\matlab\lang\run.m (line 96)
```

rather than

```
Error in run (line 96)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is simply to hack the error report that is returned by `getReport`, for example using this function to search and replace each instance of "foo" with the full path to the file -

```
function msg = getReportFull(e)

    stack = dbstack();
    stack(1) = [];

    msg = getReport(e);

    for i = 1:length(stack)
        fname = stack(i).name;
        fpath = which(stack(i).file);
        msg = strrep(msg, ['>' fname '<'], ['>' fpath '<']);
    end

end
```

Then with the following code in "foo.m" -

```
try
    disp(r3);
catch e
    disp(getReportFull(e));
end
```

you will observe this error -

```
>> run('foo.m')
Undefined function or variable 'r3'.

Error in C:\foo.m (line 2)
    disp(r3);

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\matlab\lang\run.m (line 64)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

This is absolutely an untested hack, and I make no guarantees that it won't break at a really inopportune moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when I try your function and code I still get the base name and not the full path. I'm using Matlab R2015a. Do you know why might this happen? One additional question: your solution should also work with warnings?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `dbstack()` always returns an empty array.  No idea how to fix it.

Comment: I tried using `try; surf;catch ME;disp(ME);disp(ME.stack);end` but when calling the `foo.m` file with `run('foo')`, the `ME.stack` is empty.

Comment: It is surprising that `dbstack` always returns an empty array. Are you calling it from within a function, or just calling it in the base workspace?

Comment: My mistake. It works just fine with `dbstack`. The only problem with your approach is that it doesn't work with errors like this one: `disp('foo' 1)` or with warnings. Any idea how to fix those cases?

Comment: Apparently there is no way to get a stack trace for syntax errors or warnings (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32895429/2149400)). Thanks for you answer.