# How to catch syntax errors?

Tags: matlab

If I run the following `foo.m` file with `run('foo.m')`:

```
try
    disp(r3)
catch ME
    disp('Exception handling.')
end
```

I correctly get:

```
Exception handling.
```

However if I replace `disp(r3)` by `disp('foo' 1)` then I get:

```
Error: File: C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\foo.m Line: 23 Column: 16
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Why am I not catching this error with `catch ME`? How can I catch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a syntax error in your file, not a single line of code is broken, the full file is broken because it can not be parsed. Matlab will refuse to "understand" any code you write in your `foo.m`, including your try/catch. You have to write your try/catch into another function which calls the `foo.m`

```
try
    foo()
catch ME
    disp('Exception handling.')
end
```

As the matlab interpreter will highlight all syntax errors to you without running the code, you typically don't need to check for syntax errors on runtime.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So unless I use your approach there is no way to get a `ME.stack` for syntax errors?

Comment: There is nothing you can do in the foo.m because a syntax error causes Matlab to ignore the full file. For more details about the problem you can use `mlint`, but that's basically what you see in the editor.